# How to NOT show "Update Table of Contents" dialog box in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to suppress the appearance of the "Update Table of Contents" when I update the table of contents in MS Word (by positioning the cursor on it ad pressing F9)?

(I always want to "Update entire table", so why asking for it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This web site](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/stop-asking-update-entire-table-contents-t3105140.html) says it's impossible.  [This one](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=67958) is more ambitious, and suggests that you define the following VBA function:

```
Sub UpdateTableOfContents()
    Dim oStory As Range
    Dim toc As TableOfContents
    Dim tof As TableOfFigures
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        Do
            oStory.Fields.Update
            Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
        Loop Until oStory Is Nothing
    Next
    
    For Each toc In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
        toc.Update
    Next
    
    For Each tof In ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures
        tof.Update
    Next
End Sub
```

and map it to a toolbar button and/or keyboard shortcut.  Disclaimer: I did not write this code, and I do not vouch for it in any way.